# Python 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

Python 3.3.2 import json & urllib.request

Json

```
[{"link":"www.google.com","orderid":"100000222"},
{"link":"www.google.com","orderid":"100000222"},
{"link":"www.google.com","orderid":"100000222"}]
```

print(response.info())

```
Date: Sun, 20 Oct 2013 07:06:51 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.12
Content-Length: 145
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
```

Codes

```
url = "http://www.Link.com"
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    request.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)')
    request.add_header('Content-Type','application/json')
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

    decodedRes = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    json_object = json.load(decodedRes)
```

The following are my codes 
Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\python.py", line 57, in <module>
    checkLink()
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\python.py", line 50, in checkLink
    json_object = json.load(decodedRes)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 271, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
>>> .
```

Any idea how i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) instead of `json.load`.

```
json.loads(decodedRes)
```

- [`json.load`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) accept file-like object.

---

```
>>> import json
>>> json.load('{"a": 1}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 286, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
>>> json.loads('{"a": 1}')
{u'a': 1}
```

---

Alternatively you can pass response object to `json.load`:

```
## decodedRes = response.read().decode('utf-8')
json_object = json.load(response)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing the `json.load()` with `json.loads()` . The former needs a file-stream thats the reason you are running into the attribute error.

Answer (score 4):

Following code loads json file into document. Document will have values of dict type.

```
file_name = "my_file.json"
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    document =  json.loads(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, You just need to import beautiful soup in another way.
Right now you are importing as

```
from beautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

Change it to

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```